# How to get value of Dropdown component in Ant Design (Antd), React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an issue that I can not take out the value of Dropdown to setState or something like that. Does everyone know how to fix it? I tried to access on it by onChange but still not working.

The code is below:

````
const menu = (
    <Menu onSelect={(e) => console.log(e)}>
      <Menu.Item>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Recommended
        </a>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Newest
        </a>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Lowest Price
        </a>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Highest Price
        </a>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );


<Dropdown overlay={menu1} trigger={['click']}>
            <a
              className="ant-dropdown-link"
              onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
              style={{ color: '#d46b08', fontWeight: 'bold' }}
            >
              PRICE <DownOutlined />
            </a>
</Dropdown> ```
````

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following:

```
export const items = [
  {
    label: "View Profile",
    key: "view-profile",
  },
];
```

```
  const handleDropdownItemClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
  };
```

```
 <Dropdown
            menu={{
              onClick: handleDropdownItemClick,
              items: items,
            }}
            placement="bottomRight"
            className="text-white"
          >
            <a>
              <Space>
                <DownOutlined />
              </Space>
            </a>
  </Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the value of the selected menu on dropdown, you need to assign a key on each menu item and then you can use `onClick` prop of the `Menu` component to get the value or the key.

```
const handleClick = ({key}) => {
  console.log(key)
  //you can perform setState here
}

const menu = (
  <Menu onClick={handleClick}>
    <Menu.Item key="Recommend">Recommend</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="Newest">Newest</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="Lowest Price">Lowest Price</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="Highest Price">Highest Price</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

<Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={["click"]}>
    <a
      className="ant-dropdown-link"
      onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
      style={{ color: "#d46b08", fontWeight: "bold" }}
    >
      PRICE <DownOutlined />
    </a>
</Dropdown>
```

check it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-carson-5v771?file=/index.js:602-845) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dropdown` component does not call any `onChange` property. It has `onVisibleChange` property that gets called every time the "dropdown trigger" (be it hover, click, right-click) is done. Do something like this:

```js
const SomeComponent = _props =>
{
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (<Dropdown overlay={menu} visible={visible} onVisibleChange={isVisible => setVisible(isVisible)} >
    <a className="ant-dropdown-link" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      Hover me <DownOutlined />
    </a>
  </Dropdown>);
}
```

Working pen [here](https://codepen.io/jaycodist/pen/GRZBBxR?editable=true&editors=001%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fant.design%2Fcomponents%2Fdropdown%2F)